# Run a function inside a console.log?

Tags: javascript, console

I'm reading someone's javascript code and I have a hard time understanding what they are trying to do here.

```
var add3 = add(3);
var add4 = add(4);

console.log(add3(4));
```

Can someone explain what is going on inside the `console.log()` here?

Is `console.log` just taking the `add3` value and automatically adds it to a integer 4?

Thanks

Comment: what's the definition of add() ?. it has to be a function that returns function. by the way you have to add language tag. maybe this is javascript?

Comment: It's just calling `console.log` on the result of `add3(4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.console` is how your browser gives feedback on the document it has downloaded and parsed. You can usually see it by pressing F12 and then clicking the "console" tab. It's a good substitute for `alert`, but you can also write JavaScript directly into it and then click "Run" (or press enter if it's a one-line command box). That's much easier than writing it to a file, saving it, refreshing, and seeing what happens.

Not knowing anything about your add function, it looks like it's meant to show an example of [currying](https://medium.com/the-javascript-collection/ce6da2d324fe). So instead of saying:

```
function add(x, y){
   return x + y;
}
```

You write:

```
function add(x){
    return function(y){
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var add3 = add(3); //returns a function that will add 3 to anything
console.log(add3(4)); //returns 7.
console.log(add(3)(4)); //also returns 7.
```

This seems like a silly way to do it, but it's a way to generate functions on the fly. If I did `add(3)` to the first example, it would break and say "y is undefined" in the console. Using the curried example, `var add3 = add(3)` is like saying "well, I don't know what I want to add three to yet, so `add3` will just be another function that will add 3 to anything."

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` outputs its argument to the console.
Its arument (`add3(4)`) is a function call, that calls the function `add3` with the argument `4`.

`add3` is a function that is generated by `add`.

The function `add` looks lke this (probably):

```
function add(n) {
   return function(x) {
      return n + x;
   }
}
```